# RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, netlink

When I run this cmd:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root red limit 51200000 min 128000 max 512000 avpkt 1024 burst 200 ecn probability 0.5
```

i get

```
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
```

I have configured the kernel for `netfilters`, and all the networking options in `menuconfig`.

I don't understand why this error occurs. I'm using `iproute2-2.6.23` and Fedora 8.

This was working fine on my laptop, but not on my Desktop PC?

Comment: Check `dmesg` output? There may be error messages there. Also check SELinux logs, I could imagine a shell may not have privileges for Netlink.

Comment: kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
EXT3 FS on sda1, internal journal
EXT3-fs: mounted filesystem with ordered data mode.
Adding 1835000k swap on /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol01.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:1835000k
NET: Registered protocol family 10
lo: Disabled Privacy Extensions
Clocksource tsc unstable (delta = -117591543 ns)
eth0: no IPv6 routers present
this is what i got as Demesd output                                                , I have got one more doubt, is it because of the SELINUX status???

Comment: with fedora 19 with selinux actived this work "tc qdisc add dev p4p1 root red limit 51200000 min 128000 max 512000 avpkt 1024 burst 200 ecn probability 0.5"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RTNETLINK answers :No such file or directory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513981/rtnetlink-answers-no-such-file-or-directory-error)

Answer (score 2):

The error could be due to a lack of support for traffic control in Linux kernel.

Here is an excerpt from documentation that lists kernel compilation options needed for proper operation of traffic control functionality in Linux:

Source: [Traffic Control HOWTO - Kernel requirements](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/software.html#s-kernel)

> ```
> #
> # QoS and/or fair queueing
> #
> CONFIG_NET_SCHED=y
> CONFIG_NET_SCH_CBQ=m
> CONFIG_NET_SCH_HTB=m
> CONFIG_NET_SCH_CSZ=m
> CONFIG_NET_SCH_PRIO=m
> CONFIG_NET_SCH_RED=m
> CONFIG_NET_SCH_SFQ=m
> CONFIG_NET_SCH_TEQL=m
> CONFIG_NET_SCH_TBF=m
> CONFIG_NET_SCH_GRED=m
> CONFIG_NET_SCH_DSMARK=m
> CONFIG_NET_SCH_INGRESS=m
> CONFIG_NET_QOS=y
> CONFIG_NET_ESTIMATOR=y
> CONFIG_NET_CLS=y
> CONFIG_NET_CLS_TCINDEX=m
> CONFIG_NET_CLS_ROUTE4=m
> CONFIG_NET_CLS_ROUTE=y
> CONFIG_NET_CLS_FW=m
> CONFIG_NET_CLS_U32=m
> CONFIG_NET_CLS_RSVP=m
> CONFIG_NET_CLS_RSVP6=m
> CONFIG_NET_CLS_POLICE=y
> ```
>
> A kernel compiled with the above set of options will provide modular
> support for almost everything discussed in this documentation. The
> user may need to **modprobe** *`module`* before using a given feature.

Answer (score 0):

On my system your command autoloads the `sch_red` module. The question is rather old so on a modern system the autoloading should work fine if you have the required module. Check if you miss the kernel module by running:

```
modprobe sch_red
```

If it prints nothing, then retry running `tc` command and see if it helps.

If not, ensure you have `CONFIG_NET_SCH_RED` (Random Early Detection) compiled in your kernel. [More info at kernel documentation](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/NET_SCH_RED.html).

Answer (score 0):

I got this one after compiling the (in-tree) ralink wifi drivers on a system that did not include the usual array of pre-built modules.  The modules loaded and the interface was there, but could not be set up:

```
ip link set wlanB up
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
```

(Yes, `wlanB` is correct.)  Eventually figured out the system was also missing the usual array of *firmware* in `/lib/firmware`.  This was fixed with `apt install firmware-ralink`.