# RTNETLINK answers :No such file or directory error

Tags: linux

```
1. ETH=$1
2. LATENCY=$2
3. LOSS=$3
4. JITTER=$4
5. BW=$5
6. sudo /sbin/tc qdisc del dev eth0 root
7. sudo /sbin/tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: netem delay $LATENCY $JITTER 
8. sudo /sbin/tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:1 handle 10: netem loss $LOSS
9. sudo /sbin/tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 10:1 handle 20: htb default 1
10.sudo /sbin/tc class add dev eth0 parent 20: classid 0:1 htb rate $BW ceil $BW
11.sudo /sbin/tc qdisc show
```

The above code results in:

```
RTNETLINK answers :No such file or directory
```

error on line 8,9,10 upon execution.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803069/rtnetlink-answers-no-such-file-or-directory?rq=1 ?

Comment: Have you tried using `tc qdisc list` to see what is in effect? This error sometimes means you are referring to a non-existent entry.

Comment: For anyone else who gets this on `tc qdisc del dev ...` and runs acress this question, the problem can also be that everything was already deleted.

Answer (score 12):

The problem is with missing kernel modules and/or kernel support.  Make sure you can run

```
modprobe sch_netem
```

I also had to rebuild the kernel after I enabled because there's something built-in that is enabled after you enable network emulation.

See also http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=285408 and http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem

Comment: BTW, in my case I was also getting a frustrating error that looks identical to this one.  But I was trying to use `tc qdisc change...` when I meant to use `tc qdisc add...`.  The error message is the same.  Go figure.

Comment: I can run modprobe `sch_netem` command, it doesn't give any errors. Also `lsmod | grep -i sch_netem` returns `sch_netem              17306  0`. But still `qdisk change` command gives me error: `RTNETLINK answers :No such file or directory`

Comment: @DavidDombrowsky, thanks for spotting it, I was just trying the second example line from http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem, which "change"s instead of "add"ing.

Answer (score 6):

`RTNETLINK answers :No such file or directory` comes for 2 reason.

- Executing `tc qdisc` with wrong options
- Or Kernel module `sch_netem`
  is missing

So check first `sch_netem` is installed in your machine by using command `lsmod -l`. If it is missing install using command `modprobe sch_netem`.

Even after installing sch_netem, if you get this same error means you are executing with wrong option. For example you can add a impairment on a network interface using `ip qdisc add dev ...`. Similarly for removing this you can do `ip qdisc delete dev...`. If you are trying to delete an impairment without any prior add means, then also you get this error. And also for wrong options also you get this error.

Comment: I ran into this and a missing module was indeed the culprit. In my case I needed restart after kernel upgrade had cleared out all the modules for the kernel verison I was currently running (this was on raspbian).

Answer (score 2):

Your handles and parent handles don't match. e.g change to:

```
7. sudo /sbin/tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1:1 netem delay $LATENCY $JITTER 
8. sudo /sbin/tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:1 handle 10:1 netem loss $LOSS
9. sudo /sbin/tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 10:1 handle 20:1 htb default 1
10.sudo /sbin/tc class add dev eth0 parent 20:1 classid 0:1 htb rate $BW ceil $BW
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I am running Fedora Core 27.  In order to get the module installed, I had to use

```
sudo dnf install install kernel-modules-extra
```

That's not intuitively obvious.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but the problem still occur, so.

To understand more about the problem you can check [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1330333/what-causes-rtnetlink-answers-no-such-process-when-using-ifdown-command) and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/437598/what-can-cause-rtnetlink-answers-no-such-process-when-adding-a-route) .

As a workaround to solve the problem, flush the interface config with :

Please read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1298874/restore-server-network-after-ip-addr-flush-dev-eth0) before executing the command, you maybe locked when you are remotely connecting through the interface you are working on.

```
sudo ip addr flush dev eth0
```